# How to use reload/refresh when click cross then jquery modal will be close

Tags: php, jquery

I have used same form for adding and edtting data. Adding and Editting is done successfully and I am refreshing after editing and adding. But I need some solution which is below

My jquery code is below

```
$(".update_vehicle_info").click(function(){
     var hdn_id = $(this).attr('data-hdn_id');
     $("#vehicle_form_div").find("#hdn_id").val(hdn_id);
     var post_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/spc_con/get_vehicle_info_data/" + hdn_id;
        $('#hdn_id').empty();
        $.getJSON(post_url, function(response){
        document.getElementById('financial_year_id').value = response.financial_year_id;
        document.getElementById('vehicle_id').value = response.vehicle_id;
        document.getElementById('brand_id').value = response.brand_id;
        document.getElementById('country_id').value = response.country_id;
        document.getElementById('reg_no').value = response.reg_no;
        document.getElementById('capacity').value = response.capacity;
        document.getElementById('running').value = response.running;
        document.getElementById('serviceable').value = response.serviceable;
        document.getElementById('condemned').value = response.condemned;
     });
     $("#vehicle_form_div").dialog("open");
 });
```

I have screen shoot which is below
[image]

If i click edit button, if i don't edit now and if click Add Vehicle Info then edit field value has stayed but

I need when i click edit and click cross without editing. Then Page will be refresh/reload which if i click Add Vehicle Info then every field Data won't stay it.

How to solve it, Please help me.

Comment: You should consider re-reading your question after posting

Comment: Thank a lot, php_nub_qq. I have seen Previous question but i don't get solution But Can you help me? How?

Answer (score 0):

UPD:
give to each of your tr some unique id, for example `<tr id="tr_pk_23">...</tr>` where 23 is a primary key of the row in you databse.

```
<button onClick="showModalForm(this,23);">EDIT</button>

function  showModalForm(button,id){
var $tr = $(button).closest('tr');
/*
* Send ajax request to your php script /myScript.php?id=23
* Find data in database by id, and generate modal form with php, send it back to browser append to body and show it to user.
*/
}
```

Update button in modal form must be an ajaxButton. So onClick should be assigned as function

```
<button onClick="saveDataAndUpdateRow(this,23);">UPDATE</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function saveDataAndUpdateRow(button,id){
var $form = $(button).closest('form');
var data = $form.serialize();
/*
* Send data to another script, save your data in DB and generate a new <tr> with updated values
*/
var $new_tr = @ajaxresponse;
var $old_tr = $('#tr_pk_'+id);
$old_tr.after($new_tr);
$old_tr.remove();
}
```

Feel free to ask me any questions about this concept.

Comment: Thank you Anatoliy Gusarov. Basically I want that when i click cross in mordal form then it will be close and will be refresh/reload. Can I clear to you. If you have any suggestion please write the code in answer.